# Routine to win muscle mass

Tags: muscle-mass

I am confused since there is so much information about possible exercise routines, and I don't know which one is more accurate for me.
**Age:** 28 
**Height:** 183 cm = 6 feet
**Weight:** 158.73 pounds = 72 kg

I know I have to eat and sleep well and I am working into that. I try to get one food each 4 hours approximately.
I take some whey protein after gym and before go sleep (50 gr. per day, only on training days). During breakfast I usually eat low-fat foods like checken breast, or brown rice with tuna, and in the middle of the day some low-fat soda crackers with low-fat cheese.

- I can go between 5 and 6 times by week to gym (depending on the week). At first some people suggest me to make a routine of 3 days by week because otherwise I would overtrain and get bad results. Some tells me that it is better to train all muscles on three days, and others tell me that I can split routine in 2 muscles each day, for example:
- Monday (Chest and shoulder)
- Wednesday (triceps and legs)
- Friday (biceps and

Comment: My answers [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) and [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3963/1771) might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mixture of previous answers should address your question:

- [Any suggestions on how I could improve my workout routine?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/any-suggestions-on-how-i-could-improve-my-workout-routine/6930#6930)
- [Need to get back into shape. Is there a slightly lighter p90x type-thing?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6553/need-to-get-back-into-shape-is-there-a-slightly-lighter-p90x-type-thing/6587#6587)

These previous questions address how a person in your training condition (a novice) should best add strength with a simple, focused, effective training program.

In summary, the recommendation is for a full-body, 3-times-a-week training program based around three five compound barbell lifts: squat, deadlift, bench press, overhead press, and power clean.

You'll get stronger and add weight to each lift every workout for several months. Given your age, height, and weight, you have plenty of room to grow in terms of strength, and are a perfect fit for a novice-level, general strength program like Starting Strength or Stronglifts 5x5.

(More details in the linked answers.)

About your nutrition, on these programs, you will need to eat a lot more to support the strength and muscle gains that they will be trying to stimulate. You will be eating more, and eating more frequently, probably snacking almost constantly. Increasing your fat intake will help your strength gains, since it is a very easy source of calories. Since I started strength training, I see low-fat food as a waste of my time... why would I eat 0% yogurt if I can eat 10% yogurt? Same amount of time, but so many more calories!