# Can I lose fat but stay the same weight?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, body-weight-lift

Recently I've been doing kickboxing workouts which involve high-intensity cardio with some free weights and body weight movements. This has been awesome at helping me trim down and tone up, I've gone from 223lbs down to 205lbs in about 3 months. Though, now I would like to stay around the same weight but continue with the trimming and fat loss that I've been seeing.

So my question is, Is there a workout regimen for something like this or am I going to have to lose more weight and then bulk back up with lifting?

UPDATE:

The diet that I have been trying to follow during the past 3 months is someone along the lines of:

```
5am  - Yogurt.
6    - Class till 7
730  - Peanut buyer toast with a banana
1030 - Small snack of nuts
1230 - Frozen vegetables and grilled chicken
3    - Small snack of nuts
530  - Yogurt
730  - Spinach salad and grilled chicken
```

If there are any changes to my eating habits that might help me reach my goals those suggestions would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Can you also edit your question to include information about your diet too? I've been through what you're asking. After 5 years of regular and constant martial arts training, I've lost fat but also gained muscle. Yet I'm still the same weight as 5 years ago. I also changed my diet as well (coming off college food, back home to my parents' cooking, and then moving out and eating on my own). There's probably an effect, but I don't know how much.

Comment: @MattChan I've updated my question to reflect my general eating habits for the past 3 months. I've only recently been eating like this because, I like you, have been moving around and recent college grad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you begin a general strength training program focused on full-body workouts using barbells (squats, deadlifts, bench press, overhead press), and feed yourself to support this muscle growth, you can simultaneously add muscle, trim fat, and hold your current weight. *[Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.com/)* and *[Stronglifts](http://stronglifts.com/)* are two popular examples of this type of program. (More detail about these programs are in other answers, [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6553/need-to-get-back-into-shape-is-there-a-slightly-lighter-p90x-type-thing/6587#6587) and [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/stronglifts-5x5-an-effective-program/5774#5774).)

It may take some fine-tuning of your diet to exactly hold weight, so you may drop or increase weight slightly if you're not eating exactly the right amount, but you should be able to get close, but your body fat % should continue to decrease regardless of these small variations.

Comment: Do you have any links to those programs?

Comment: Done. I didn't want to replicate too much info from other answers.