# What should be my first goals and supplements when starting a bodybuilding program?

Tags: diet, workout, supplements, programs

I'm 20 years old. I am 85 kg (about 187 pounds), and my height is 179 centimeters. I don't really have any muscle. I have belly fat. I was a swimmer 4 years ago, but I haven't done any sports for 4 years. It's time to change :)

I'll go to a gym. There is a guy who will help me as a coach. He's actually not a professional coach but is just manager of the gym. Because of this, I don't trust him.

I just checked a few websites, and I found two workout goals on bodybuilding.com: **lose fat** and **gain muscle** . I'm not sure. Which one should be my goal? I'm fatty but I don't want to lose too much weight. I want to stay the same weight (maybe lose 10-20 pounds) and gain muscle. I went to gym for a few months 1-2 years ago, so I know  some basic terminology. But I don't know anything about creating a training plan. I found [this plan](http://stronglifts.com/stronglifts-5x5-beginner-strength-training-program/) on internet, but I don't know if it is suitable for me? I don't know where should I start.

I don't have any diet program. What diet should I follow? Should I start using supplements? I am also lactose intolerant.

Comment: You might find this recent question of interest: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7439/22

Comment: @Greg,  thank you but i was read that before asking this question.  I think we are totally different situation with that question's owner.  He is doing kickbox and i'm starting to sport totally new,  this is one of differences :) i have a lots of fat and i want to burn them,  he has small amount of fat.  Thank you :)

Comment: Stronglifts and Starting Strength are the two most popular novice strength programs on the internet now, you will be served well by choosing one of them. I'll let someone else write a more detailed answer.. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're a complete beginner, you can both lose fat and gain muscle at the same time. A strength training program would be best suited to this (you can always focus more on muscle hypertrophy when you're already strong).

[Stronglifts 5x5](http://www.stronglifts.com) is a good beginner's strength training program that's also free. You don't have to do exactly that, there are multiple variations of it, but the important thing is to lift weights that are heavy enough that you can only do 5 or 6 of them. SL will start you out way below that, but you'll quickly reach the point which you really are maxing out at 5 reps.

For diet, focus on eating healthy. That you know you're lactose intolerant is a good start, but you're probably intolerant to some other foods without knowing it. Keep a food journal and also write down how you feel and at what time. That will help you figure out which foods are causing you trouble. Eliminate them from your diet. Similarly, keep foods in that seem to make you feel really good.

As with lifting in which you focus on strength first, with diet you should focus on eating real foods first, and only then think about supplements.

Comment: Hello @Robin, THank you so much for your answer. i'm staying at dormitory and, i can't eat healthy foods, and good things. Always there is vegetables on dormitory's canteen. There is meat once a week. I think i won't get enough protein. I don't like to eat in there. Because of this, i need a few more advices about eating real foods, please .

Comment: @Eray I've been in that situation, it's not pleasant. Only having meat 1x/week isn't great either, but it is better than nothing. I would say the most important thing for you in that situation is to have variety. Try to go through eating everything that's on the menu (unless it's cooked pretty badly), so you're more likely to get all the nutrients you need. In that situation, it also might be a good idea to get a multivitamin and eat one 1000mg pill per day on top of your regular food.

Comment: Is GNC's Mega Men (http://www.gnc.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4033432) good for me ? It's a little expensive, i think. Really I need this ? I hasn't any protein. Also should i use fish oil ?

Comment: I'm liking that it has more than 400IU of vitamin D, but it does look expensive. There should be something else that should be suitable. Fish oil (if properly filtered, and therefore also quite expensive) is good, but I don't think you'd need to take both.

Comment: So,  i'll looking for other multivitamins.  Which nutritions should i check while choosing a multivitamin?

Comment: That really depends on what you're not getting from your regular diet. Research what vitamins and minerals the foods you regularly eat are high in, and see what's missing, then look for a multivitamin that's high in those.